# find index position in given string by using sql

Tags: mysql, pyspark

My value is "asdsdf2739173sidfsd"
Here I want to get first and last occurrence of any number position or index in given string, please help me

Comment: mysql or pyspark? What is your final goal?

Answer (score 1):

To find the indices of the first and last occurrence of a number in a string, we can try using `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```sql
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'asdsdf2739173sidfsd' AS val
)

SELECT
    val,
    LENGTH(val) - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(val, '^[^0-9]*', '')) AS idx_first,
    LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(val, '[^0-9]*$', '')) - 1 AS idx_last
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Comment: Not so efficient version:  you can use something like `charindex` to search 0-9 numbers too. (Just sharing it here for the record) http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQLServer/String-Functions/CHARINDEXfindthefirstoccurrenceofasubstringwithinanotherstring.htm

Comment: @sam The OP appears to not be using SQL Server, but even if it were, you'd want `PATINDEX`, not `CHARINDEX`.